# Developing Neural net for predicting attendance in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

I am pretty new to Machine learning and Neural Nets. I followed https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/05/neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-and-r/ to get a basic idea of what I was looking at.

My goal is to predict the attendance at a store based on things such as temperature, weekday/weekend, rain, storm, holiday, company events, etc.

I figured I could break down most of those as 0 or 1, such as 0 for weekend, no rain, no storm, no holiday, no event and 1 for weekday, rain, storm, event, holiday

For temperature, I tried normalizing using T-T0/T1-T0 with an approximate of the max and min temperatures for the area

Some of the problems I have been running into are that the code given in the example always returns something between 0 or 1, which makes me think I had to normalize the outputs (attendance).I tried that the same way I did temperatures but predicting a min and max is difficult, even when using 0 and something absurd like 5000 (average is around 1100) the NN doesnt give the right values

I am assuming this has something to do with the Sigmoid function, and I might need to use a different activation function, but I am still new to this and could easily be overlooking something else

example data:

```
Temp: 104
Rain: 0
Holiday: 0
Weekday: 1
Attendance: 410

Temp: 106
Rain: 0
Holiday: 0
Weekday: 0
Attendance: 2338

Temp: 88
Rain: 1
Holiday: 0
Weekday: 1
Attendance: 361
```

My most recent code (I went back to the original because my edits were causing it to perform worse)

```
import numpy as np

#Input array
X=np.array([[.88,1,1,1],[.92,0,0,0],[.56,1,1,1]])

#Output
y=np.array([[410],[2338],[361]])

#Sigmoid Function
def sigmoid (x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

#Derivative of Sigmoid Function
def derivatives_sigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

#Variable initialization
epoch=25000 #Setting training iterations
lr=0.1 #Setting learning rate
inputlayer_neurons = X.shape[1] #number of features in data set
hiddenlayer_neurons = 3 #number of hidden layers neurons
output_neurons = 1 #number of neurons at output layer

#weight and bias initialization
wh=np.random.uniform(size=(inputlayer_neurons,hiddenlayer_neurons))
bh=np.random.uniform(size=(1,hiddenlayer_neurons))
wout=np.random.uniform(size=(hiddenlayer_neurons,output_neurons))
bout=np.random.uniform(size=(1,output_neurons))

for i in range(epoch):

    #Forward Propogation
    hidden_layer_input1=np.dot(X,wh)
    hidden_layer_input=hidden_layer_input1 + bh
    hiddenlayer_activations = sigmoid(hidden_layer_input)
    output_layer_input1=np.dot(hiddenlayer_activations,wout)
    output_layer_input= output_layer_input1+ bout
    output = sigmoid(output_layer_input)

    #Backpropagation
    E = y-output
    slope_output_layer = derivatives_sigmoid(output)
    slope_hidden_layer = derivatives_sigmoid(hiddenlayer_activations)
    d_output = E * slope_output_layer
    Error_at_hidden_layer = d_output.dot(wout.T)
    d_hiddenlayer = Error_at_hidden_layer * slope_hidden_layer
    wout += hiddenlayer_activations.T.dot(d_output) *lr
    bout += np.sum(d_output, axis=0,keepdims=True) *lr
    wh += X.T.dot(d_hiddenlayer) *lr
    bh += np.sum(d_hiddenlayer, axis=0,keepdims=True) *lr

print output
```

What is a good way to go about predicting this? Do I need to reform my NN or can this example be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right. The sigmoid function always returns values between 0 and 1.
Obviously, this is not a good solution for you as you are dealing with a regression problem (instead of classification).

Just drop the activation function entirely and use a linear function instead.

```
  ...
  hiddenlayer_activations = hidden_layer_input
  ...
```

Comment: Should i remove all uses of the sigmoid function? including outputs? Also, which input/outs should i normalize, if any

Comment: EDIT: removing all sigmoid and normalization (just using raw data) gives me overflow errors

Comment: You want to change every occurrence of your activation function, especially the one in your output layer. Additionally, you have to change the derivative as well. I suggest you take a more in-depth course (like the machine learning course on coursera) to grasp the concepts involved. On the other hand, if you just want a solution, use sklearn or another library that does the work for you (see sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor)

Comment: I plan to take some courses on the subject. As for this project, I am limited to a 32bit machine, so when I tried using Keras/Tensorflow I ran into issues installing them. I will give sklearn a try. In the meantime, any idea why im getting overflow?

Comment: You can install sklearn with 1 pip command. Tensorflow and Keras should is just as easy if you don't use GPUs. As for your overflow errors, your gradients are probably exploding. Try printing wout, bout on each step to see what I mean. This probably happens because you didn't change your derivative to match your activation function

Comment: With a linear activasion, what would the derivative be? If im just assigning the value as in your original answer, im not sure what the derivative of that is